# Ora2Pg: How to convert int IDs into uuid IDs

Tags: integer, database-migration, uuid, ora2pg

i'm currently benchmarking  ora2pg for an Oracle to Postgres migration, and I'm wondering if there's a way to change my IDs from integer to uuid type especially if those ids have references in other tables.
Thanks in advance for your help!
Cristina

I've tried MODIFY_TYPE and DATA_TYPE directive in ora2pg.conf  without success.
If there's no alternative I will just use ora2og for the one to one migration parts and make a custom script afterwards.